# installing FastCGI on IIS7?

Tags: php, iis-7

I am following [this article](http://sysadmingeek.com/articles/how-to-install-php-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/)

I installed all, but after I am running the test I am getting this error :

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
Detailed Error Information
Module FastCgiModule
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler PHP
Error Code 0xc0000005
Requested URL http://  localhost:80/ test.php
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php
Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous
Most likely causes:

    * IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
    * IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
    * IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
    * The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
    * The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

    * Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
    * Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
    * Verify the permissions for the DLL.
    * Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
    * Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Links and More Information This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.

View more information »

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

    * 294807
```

Comment: i only create one php page with: <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: try this and write result http://forums.iis.net/t/1149374.aspx

Answer (score 5):

In the fine print on the php.net website I noticed that:

```
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 is required for PHP 5.5
```

I ran this command from the command prompt to locate the problem

```
C:\php\php-cgi.exe C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php
```

test.php is a file I created with the following text:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like there is a problem with your permissions.
You should check what user your `php-cgi.exe` is running with (CTRL + SHIFT + END and look for the process) and find if that user has read access to your PHP install folder (something like `C:\PHP`) AND your current web root.
The latter might need also some write access.